# PostgreSQL view embedded if-statements

Tags: postgresql, view

In my database, for stores that have no rating from Reseller Ratings, they still have an entry but have `-1.0` instead of a number between `0.0` and `10.0`. The following query results in `-10.00` showing up in my view for those stores with `-1.0`. Instead, I would like either nothing or a `-` showing up in its place, but I'm not very comfortable with implementing embedded if-statements in my view. Here is my current view.

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT co_url_name AS company_url, score_combined AS stella_score, trunc(score*10, 2) AS bizrate_score,
(SELECT trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2)) AS resellerRating_score
    FROM ss_profile_co AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN "resellerRatings_ratings" AS r
        ON s.id = r.company_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM bizrate_bizrate_ratings WHERE score_name = 'Overall rating') AS b
                ON s.id = b.fk_co_id
                    ORDER BY co_url_name ASC;
```

The line `(SELECT trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2)) AS resellerRating_score` is the one that returns the negative numbers (or, for valid entries, will return a score between `0.00` and `100.00`).

Obviously, I could simply remove these entries from the database that result in this, but it's half a learning experience and half out of my hands to do so anyways.

I appreciate the help!

EDIT: Attempted an embedded if but not surprisingly got an error.

```
IF (SELECT trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2)) = -10.00 THEN NULL ELSE (SELECT trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2)) AS resellerRating_score
```

EDIT2: Figured it out. Line in question is as follows:

```
(SELECT trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2) WHERE trunc("lifetimeRating"*10, 2) > 0) AS resellerrating_score
```

/foreveralone

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN lifetimerating < 0 THEN NULL ELSE trunc(lifetimerating*10, 2) END` instead of your IF.

Comment: By all means, post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT co_url_name AS company_url
      ,score_combined AS stella_score
      ,trunc(score * 10, 2) AS bizrate_score
      ,CASE WHEN "lifetimeRating" < 0
            THEN NULL
            ELSE trunc("lifetimeRating" * 10, 2)
       END AS resellerRating_score
FROM   ss_profile_co s
LEFT   JOIN "resellerRatings_ratings" r ON r.company_id = s.id
LEFT   JOIN bizrate_bizrate_ratings   b ON b.score_name = 'Overall rating' 
                                        AND b.fk_co_id = s.id
ORDER  BY co_url_name;
```

#### Major points

- Concerning your core question: the sub-select without a `FROM` clause serves no purpose. I simplified that and use a `CASE` statement instead.
- I also simplified your `LEFT JOIN` to `bizrate_bizrate_ratings`. No sub-select necessary either. I pulled the `WHERE` clause up into the `JOIN` condition. Simpler and faster.
- I would advise not to use [mixed case identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), so you never have to use double quotes. (This probably makes @Daniels comment invalid, because `lifetimerating` != `"lifetimeRating"`